# Convert XML file into another XML file using XSL template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to convert an XML into another XML using an XSLT stylesheet.

This is the part of my input XML where I have to use XSL template(input.xml):

```
 ...
    <extension>
        <og:image>http://www.example.com/images/logos/logo-example-PNG.png</og:image>
        <og:type>article</og:type>
        <resourceName>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</resourceName>
    </extension>
   .......
```

I want my XML(output.xml) to look like this:

```
....
<MT N="og:image" V="http://www.example.com/images/logos/logo-example-PNG.png"/>
<MT N="og:type" V="article"/>
<MT N="resourceName" V="http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions"/>
...
```

I am trying to use an XSLT for this. But I am stuck at the XSL template part. I want my XSLT to go in the XPATH of extension and specify a template for every element inside of the extension to convert into this form:

```
<MT N="" V=""/>
```

"N" with the name of the tag name and "V" with the value of the tag

What should I specify in my XSLT?

```
 <xsl:template match="/extension">
    ....
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post entire XML (or enough to know repeat pattern) as XSLT unlike its sibling XPath handles an entire document even if you only need to transform a part of it. Also, namespaces usually in root tags need too be known and seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**XML:**

```
<extension xmlns:og="http://og.com">
 <og:image>http://www.example.com/images/logos/logo-example-PNG.png</og:image>
 <og:type>article</og:type>
 <resourceName>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</resourceName>
</extension>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:og="http://og.com">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="extension">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="MT">
            <xsl:attribute name="N" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="V" select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OutPut:**

```
<MT N="og:image" V="http://www.example.com/images/logos/logo-example-PNG.png"/>
<MT N="og:type" V="article"/>
<MT N="resourceName" V="http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions"/>
```

**Edited input XML:**

```
<root  xmlns:og="http://og.com">
 <extension>
  <og:image>http://www.example.com/images/logos/logo-example-PNG.png</og:image>
  <og:type>article</og:type>
  <resourceName>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</resourceName>
 </extension>
</root>
```

Here 'root' is the root element, namespace can be declared there.

Comment: More simply, you can replace the xsl:element above with `<MT N="{name()}" V="{.}"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will update as suggested.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sir, <MT N="{name()}" V="{.}"/> will give the <MT xmlns:og="http://og.com" .../> og namespace text within MT element.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Comment: You can exclude the namespace declaration if you really need to using exclude-result-prefixes. In this case I rather assumed it might be needed because the "og" prefix is used within the values of the @N attributes in the output.

Comment: @RudramuniTP Your solution is working perfectly, but my original XML doesn't have  "<extension xmlns:og="http://og.com">" this part of og. If I run my Java program which is using Saxon to convert XML by using XSLT without using the "<extension xmlns:og="http://og.com">" in my input XML, then it shows me the error which says "SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "og" for element "og:image" is not bound."

Comment: @NupurJaiswal, in my sample XML, <extension> is the root, that's why I declared namespace in that element (<extension xmlns:og="http://og.com">), usually namespaces are declared in the root element's side only. if  xmlns:og="http://og.com" is declared in your input XML, then no need to give that in <extension> element side.

Comment: @NupurJaiswal, I posted one more sample input XML.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful